# MS SQL Server restoring database from MDF & LDF not showing latest data

Tags: sql-server

The database is MS SQL Server Express 2005.  The database is in simple mode.

I am trying to restore an existing database to a new server.  I copied the MDF and LDF files to a new server.  I attached the MDF and verified that the correct LDF was associated with it.  After attaching the database, I compared the data from both databases and found that the new attached data was not current.  Why?

Comment: Do you detached database first?

Comment: No.  I was under the impression I could restore directly from MDF/LDF

Comment: You can attach from MDF/LDF but not restore... there is a RESTORE command for that.

Comment: OK.  I am pulling the MDF/LDF files from a backup copy made by Vice Versa.  The SQL Server was never stopped.  I am testing that the files can be restored from the backup.  I don't think that is possible based on these answers and comments.  Correct?

Comment: @Dave: I guess same result probably. BTW, a backup made like this is probably unusable. Best is to backup to disk using BACKUP DATABASE, then backup this file to tape etc. I'd never trust a 3rd party backup widget. If it works for you, fair enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Detach the database.
- Copy the MDF and LDF files
- Reattach on new server

I'm surprised you managed to copy the files at first because SQL Server locks the files exclusively.

You need to detach to cleanly "shut down" the database.

Answer (score 0):

Just detach database. Last transactions will be saved into database, and you can successfully attach database.